# Reference Nuget Package that targets different .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, nuget, asp.net-core, nuget-package, .net-core

After recently migrated from ASP.NET Core RC1 to RC2, I am unable to reference dlls directly anymore. Visual Studio tells me that I can only reference Nuget packages.

So I have built a local Nuget package from the assembly. I am able to install the package without any errors. I have no issues performing a `dotnet restore`. **However, I am unable to reference any of the namespaces of the assembly.**

The referenced package name is `spfcommon.dll`, and the assembly targets `.Net Framework 4.0`. My project targets `.Net Framework 4.5.1`. I don't know if the difference in target frameworks is causing this issue.

My project.json file:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": {
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "System.Runtime": "4.0.10.0"
    }
  }
},
"dependencies": {
  "Common": "4.0.0-*",
  "Data": "4.0.0-*",
  "spfcommon.dll": "1.0.1"   <-- Cannot reference namespaces
},
```

The error is:

> The type or namespace name 'SPF' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `spfcommon.dll` a dll or a package? If it's a DLL, you can't reference it directly

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci It's a package that I created locally for the dll. Here, I am referencing the package.

Comment: Can you share the nuspec of that package? Also, how did you create the package?

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar problem today, caused me a few hours grief but I found that if I deleted the "wrap" folder and then restored the packages it would work again.

Hopefully it's the same as your issue.